# Catenating Variables in bat file

Tags: string, batch-file, cmd, concatenation

I've created bat file named vk.bat . The code is as following :-

```
SET "tcs="

FOR %%A IN (%*) DO (
      Set "tcs=%tcs% -t %%A"      
)
Echo %tcs%
```

I am executing this bat from cmd as following :-

```
c:\vk.bat Apple Cat Play
```

I want the final string as `" -t Apple -t Cat -t Play"`

But I am getting final string as "-t Play" . I am not able to find out that why and how it's overwriting the previous contents of string tcs.

Comment: You are inside a code block. You need to use [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have fallen into the delayed expansion trap, like Squashman mentioned.

---

## What Is Delayed Expansion?

In earlier batch files, variables are expanded(changed to it's value) when each line is phrased.

The command processor treats the entire `for` loop as one command, so the variable `%tcs%` is treated as nothing. (Because `tcs` was previously set to nothing.

---

## How To Make Batch Variables Get Expanded At Run-Time?

To preserve compatibility with older batch files, delayed expansion feature is added. To allow the processor to do so, add this line to the start of the batch file:

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
```

and we also need to tell the processor which variables to be expanded at run-time, to do so, change the following:

```
From  -> To
%var% -> !var!
```

Note only `%n%` variables can be changed to `!n!`. Metavariables like `%%G`/`%G` and `%0` cannot be changed.

---

Here's is the fixed code using delayed expansion.:

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET "tcs="

FOR %%G IN (%*) DO (
      SET "tcs=!tcs! -t %%G"      
)
ECHO %tcs%
```

Answer (score 0):

## DelayedExpansion-free Solution

Using the `call` command, we can emulate the delayed expansion. Take a look at this example

```
call command %%foo%% = setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
                       command !foo!
```

According to your case, the code should be changed to this:

```
SET "tcs="

FOR %%G IN (%*) DO (
      CALL SET "tcs=%%tcs%% -t %%G"      
)
ECHO %tcs%
```

---

#### Some Buggy Behaviour With `CALL`

`Call` doesn't handle redirection characters and some special characters properly:

- &
- |
- <
- >
- "foo^bar"

  The redirection of the first 4 examples won't function as intended, while in the last example, the caret(`^`) will be doubled. Source: [SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html)